# Newton-Cartan from GR

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, speed-of-light, approximations

How does [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) reduce to [Newton-Cartan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cartan_theory) Field Equation $R_{tt}=4\pi G \rho$ in Newtonian Limit? I understand its direct derivation from geodesics in weak field, what I am curious about is how EFE reduces to NCFE, meaning a direct derivation of NCFE from EFE.